# Ratio of target met and not met in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

Table Emp

```
EmployeeID   Target_status   
1           Achieved     
2           Not achieved  
5           Not Achieved  
6           Achieved      
3           Achieved      
4           Not Achieved
```

Table Site

```
  EmpID      Site
     1       SiteA
     2       SiteB
     3       SiteA
     4       SiteA
     5       SiteA
     6       SiteA
```

How to find the ratio of number of people who achieved the target versus number of people who didn't achieve the targets from Site A (ANSWER: 3/2)

Code tried:

```
(select cast(count(a.Target_status)/count(d.Target_status) as float) 
from Emp a
inner join Site b on a.EmployeeId = b.EmpId
where Site = 'SiteA' and a.Target_status='Achieved' ) e
full outer join
(
(select * from Emp a
inner join Site b on a.EmployeeId = b.EmpId
where Site = 'SiteA' and a.Target_status='Not Achieved' ) d

on e.employeeID=d.empid
```

Error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'full'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'd'.
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: check your `(` matches with `)` . Looks like is one extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN e.Target_status = 'Achieved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
             SUM(CASE WHEN e.Target_status = 'Not Achieved' THEN 1 END) ratio
FROM Emp e INNER JOIN Site s 
ON e.EmployeeId = s.EmpId
WHERE s.Site = 'SiteA';
```

Not that the `CASE` expression in the 2nd `SUM()` does not have an `ELSE` part, so that in case there are no employees with `Target_status = 'Not Achieved'` the result will be `NULL` and not `0` which would throw a "Divide by zero error".

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fe4549e63777f1f8daa12e741d128633).

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in a simple way

```
select CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN a.Target_status='Achieved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR) +'/'+CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN a.Target_status='Not Achieved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR) Ratio
from Emp a
inner join Site b on a.EmployeeId = b.EmpId
where Site = 'SiteA'
```

**This will return**

```
3/2
```